# Why Python doesnt see an existing module

Tags: python

I made an app for analysing data, all in one file, but i read that it needs to be made in objective style. Trying to make it objective I get an error that module doesnt have attribute (which it has)

Tried to disable linting and organise code in a different way but end up with this error all the time

file - analyser.py

```
import argparse
import helper

class analyser:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cli(self):

     #some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    analyser.cli
    helper.analyse(arguments)
```

file - helper.py

```
import csv

class helper:

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def analyse(self, arguments):

    #code
```

I get
AttributeError: module 'analyser' has no attribute 'analyse'

Comment: You don't need to separate out your class definitions into different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `helper` does not have an attribute `analyse`. However, the *class* `helper` does have one. You can do one of the following to access the `analyse` function:

```
from helper import helper
...
helper.analyse(arguments)
```

Or

```
import helper
...
helper.helper.analyse(arguments)
```

At the moment, the 2 classes `helper` and `analyser` are redundant. You may be better off just using functions. Object-oriented programming is useful in certain circumstances to encapsulate data and for abstraction, but functional programming has its own uses and it is good to know when to use either.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see a reason for using objectivity here, but this particular task explicitly says they want me to do it objectively so i need to comply. Again thanks for help

Comment: In that case, you may want to only use 1 class and have all of your methods inside this class rather than creating multiple classes with single methods in them. You could store your data in the class too.